# PHP Amazon product API => How to loop over an array of unknown levels...?

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to loop over the browsenodes array the Amazon Product API returns for a requested product with ItemLookup but I can not figure out how to do it reliably since the returned array has always a different amount of levels.

I have looked for other answers here that suggest the SimpleXML iterator for example, but that doesn't work and throws an exception because it could not be parsed as xml...

The array that is returned by amazon looks like this:

```
[BrowseNodes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [BrowseNode] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 172659
                        [Name] => Televisions
                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1266092011
                                        [Name] => Television & Video
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 493964
                                                        [Name] => Categories
                                                        [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 172282
                                                                        [Name] => Electronics
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Or this for example:

```
[BrowseNodes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3764321
                                [Name] => Chin Strips
                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 702368011
                                                [Name] => Snore Reducing Aids
                                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3764271
                                                                [Name] => Sleep & Snoring
                                                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3760941
                                                                                [Name] => Health Care
                                                                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3760931
                                                                                                [Name] => Products
                                                                                                [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                                                                                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                                    (
                                                                                                        [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                                            (
                                                                                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3760901
                                                                                                                [Name] => Health & Personal Care
                                                                                                            )

                                                                                                    )

                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I somehow need to reliably loop through all items in the first level of the array that contain the category and subcategory info.

if the array has more levels [1], [2] etc, those would need to be skipped.

The info I need always sits in the first level->name and then the last level->name where iscategoryroot => 1

But since the depth is always different I simply can not figure out how to do it :(

What can I do in this situation? How would I go to loop over arrays like this?

Thanks ! :)

---

EDIT:

---

So I connect to the api with curl, and build a simplexml object from it:

```
/* include stuff */
include("amazon_api_class.php");
include("functions.php");

// create new amazon object
$obj = new AmazonProductAPI();

try 
    {
        $result = $obj->getItemByAsin("B004NPND20,B004VRJ3E2,B000EM91FY,B00004Z2HD,B00004Z2HR,B00004Z2HZ,B00002ND60,B000N54BDO,B000BQKBCK,B0000225IO");


    } catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


// loop over the returned object and extract the details we need
foreach($result->Items->Item as $key => $item){
```

Then the complete output of the browse nodes array looks like this (always different though)

```
[BrowseNodes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [BrowseNode] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 172659
                        [Name] => Televisions
                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1266092011
                                        [Name] => Television & Video
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 493964
                                                        [Name] => Categories
                                                        [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 172282
                                                                        [Name] => Electronics
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 13900851
                        [Name] => Electronics Features
                        [Children] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 51549011
                                                [Name] => Featured Categories
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3302711
                                                [Name] => Gold Merchants
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 2354568011
                                                [Name] => Specialty Boutique
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 172282
                                        [Name] => Electronics
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1288264011
                        [Name] => All product
                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267878011
                                        [Name] => Products
                                        [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267877011
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3545110011
                        [Name] => Home Entertainment
                        [Children] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3547652011
                                                [Name] => Blu-Ray Players
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3547650011
                                                [Name] => DVD Players
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 1294446011
                                                [Name] => Televisions
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1294447011
                                        [Name] => Electronics
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267878011
                                                        [Name] => Products
                                                        [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267877011
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1293318011
                        [Name] => TVs
                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267879011
                                        [Name] => Special Features
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267877011
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1293319011
                        [Name] => Electronics
                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267879011
                                        [Name] => Special Features
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 1267877011
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And I always only need the first array key and then the first and last sub-item in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but you can probably take the idea from here.

```
function getCategory($node) {
    $category = array();
    $category["Category"] = (string)$node->Name;

    if (isset($node->Ancestors)) {
        do {
            $node = $node->Ancestors->BrowseNode;
            if (isset($node->IsCategoryRoot) && isset($node->Ancestors)) {
                $category["Root"] = (string)$node->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
                break;
            }
        } while (isset($node->Ancestors));
    }

    return $category;
}
```

You could easily do this on a recursive function too, but I believe its more readable looping through it. (and efficient too).

Comment: Hm no that won't do it sadly, might not explained myself well enough :)

I don't need to loop through all levels of the array, I need to loop through the first levels sublevel of the array...

so if the array returned has 5 keys, I need to loop through all sublevels of [0] where I need to extract the first Name value and the last Name value where IsCategoryRoot = 1

I tried your example,  but it only loops through all the keys of an array as far as I can see?

Comment: Marc it will iterate at all sublevels, of each top-level array in $browseNodes. It shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to your needs, I've edited it for ya.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it loops only the first levels of the array... How can I explain that better haha :)

hmmm, the output of your code gives me the ->Name field of the first level of each key, but what I need is the sub-levels, what I posted above... From the first key, and the depth of these levels i dynamic so I can not simply go ->BrosweNode->Ancenstors-Name or so. In my first example array the value i would need is: [Name] => Televisions and the last one [Name] => Electronics... is that understandable what I try to convey here? Sorry, I'm still learning coding :)

Comment: In the second array I would need for example:
[Name] => Chin Strips & [Name] => Health & Personal Care

But because the depth of these sub levels is always different I do not know how to access the values every time reliable, in all scenarios

Comment: Marc this code SHOULD do what you want. It gets the first level name, and then go down the tree to until it finds the browseNode with IsCategoryRoot. Could you post a sample XML? I would be willing to look into that for you.

Comment: It should get: The First `browseNode`'s Name (top-level, "Chin Strips" in the second example), and go all the way down to the "Health Care" which it will save in the `$categories` array since the next node is the root category.

Comment: I don't have sample xml sadly, I retrieve the data via curl and output a simplexml object, tried to get xml but I honestly don't know how :D

Can I post one item from the object here? But this is a lot of code...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8988/discussion-between-nathan-and-marc)